# Gatling - value check is not a member of io.gatling.http.request.builder.Http

Tags: scala, gatling

Trying to capture jsession id from string 
    `jsessionid=an121kj533n232j53531314353.tomcat_17221212_1101`

in `Gatling 2.2.3` using the following function
    `.check(regex(""jsessionid=\"(.*?).tomcat"").saveAs("jsessid"))`
getting following error during compilation

```
`[ERROR] i.g.c.ZincCompiler$ - C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\gatling-2.2.3\user-files\simulations\RecordedSimulation.scala:31: value check is not a member of io.gatling.http.request.builder.Http possible cause: maybe a semicolon is missing before 'value check'? 
 15:09:05.780 [ERROR] i.g.c.ZincCompiler$ - .check(regex("\"jsessionid=\"(.*?).tomcat").saveAs("jsessid"))`
```

Added the code for better presentation of the issue. I am new to Scala/Gatling, any help is really appreciated. Actual Code

`import scala.concurrent.duration._`
`import io.gatling.core.Predef._`
`import io.gatling.http.Predef._`
`import io.gatling.jdbc.Predef._`

`class RecordedSimulation extends Simulation {`

```
val httpProtocol = http
    .baseURL("https://XXXXX.net:9191")
    .inferHtmlResources(BlackList(""".*\.js""", """.*\.css""", """.*\.gif""", """.*\.jpeg""", """.*\.jpg""", """.*\.ico""", """.*\.woff""", """.*\.(t|o)tf""", """.*\.png"""), WhiteList())
    .acceptHeader("text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8")
    .acceptEncodingHeader("gzip, deflate")
    .acceptLanguageHeader("en-US,en;q=0.5")
    .userAgentHeader("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0")

val headers_2 = Map("Accept" -> "image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5")

val uri1 = "https://login-qa.XXXX.net:443/minderagent/SmMakeCookie.ccc"
val uri2 = "https://login-qa.XXXX.net:443/minderagent"
val uri3 = "https://XXXXX.svr.us.XXXXX.net:9191/web"

val scn = scenario("RecordedSimulation")
    // Launch
    .exec(http("request_0")
        .get("/web/")
        .check(regex("\"jsessionid=\"(.*?).tomcat").saveAs("jsessid")))
    .pause(24)
    // Login
    .exec(http("request_1")
        .post(uri2 + "/SSOlogin.fcc")
        .formParam("SMENC", "ISO-8859-1")
        .formParam("SMLOCALE", "US-EN")
        .formParam("location", "")
        .formParam("target", "HTTPS://XXXXX.svr.us.XXXXX.net:9191/web/")
        .formParam("smauthreason", "0")
        .formParam("smagentname", "XXXX+xirJXXJhSPoyD4OiZyLt1C0KEntKHOu0n3c9AIjJ0oMQ7vtB2z2PtaGfRQrMCNbVlFycMzQmdjGuQMXXXXXhnprOFAn8")
        .formParam("postpreservationdata", "")
        .formParam("USER", "XXXXX")
        .formParam("PASSWORD", "XXXXX")
        .resources(http("request_2")
        .get("/web/common/images/cme.jpg;jsessionid=${jsessid}.tomcat_1232323_11002")
        .headers(headers_2),
        http("request_3")
        .get("/cmeweb/common/images/Title.jpg;jsessionid=${jsessid}.tomcat_1232323_11002")
        .headers(headers_2),
        http("request_4")
        .get("/web/common/images/logo_chase.gif;jsessionid=${jsessid}.tomcat_1232323_11002")
        .headers(headers_2),
        http("request_5")
        .get(uri1 + "?SMSESSION=QUERY&PERSIST=0&TARGET=$SM$https%3a%2f%2fvsin8u4784%2esvr%2eus%2eXXXXX%2enet%3a9191%2ffavicon%2eico"),
        http("request_6")
        .get(uri2 + "/SSOlogin.fcc?TYPE=33554433&REALMOID=06-000a5275-6315-16fb-8d7a-895aa9454077&GUID=&SMAUTHREASON=0&METHOD=GET&SMAGENTNAME=$SM$UKnA%2bxirJXXJhSPoyD4OiZyLt1C0KEntKHOu0n3c9AIjJ0oMQ7vtB2z2PtaGfRQrMCNbVlFycMzQmdjGuQMhnpYx0srOFAn8&TARGET=$SM$HTTPS%3a%2f%2fvsin8u4784%2esvr%2eus%2eXXXXX%2enet%3a9191%2ffavicon%2eico")))
    .pause(12)
    // Click Batch
    .exec(http("request_7")
        .get("/web/batchtracking!view.action;jsessionid=${jsessid}.tomcat_1232323_11002"))
    .pause(13)
    // Search Batch
    .exec(http("request_8")
        .post("/cmeweb/batchtracking!doSearch.action")
        .formParam("startDate", "07/22/2016")
        .formParam("endDate", "07/22/2016")
        .formParam("cmeUser", "")
        .formParam("sortColumnAlias", "Default"))

setUp(scn.inject(atOnceUsers(1))).protocols(httpProtocol)}
```

Not getting the above error, when I move .check function under launch tag, rite after get.
But need help in capturing the value in jessionid 'jsessionid=**an121kj533n232j53531314353**.tomcat_17221212_1101'

Comment: Can You provide the whole code whole code here.? on which the check function is applied probably the case is that you are applying the check function on the wrong object. If you can provide the whole code that would really be helpful !

Comment: Hi Shivansh Srivastava, I have updated the post with code. Kindly take a look any provide input. Used above function based on examples I found on Stack. There aren't many examples in documentation, so not sure if I am missing anything. Appreciate all your help!

Comment: Hi, Shivansh Srivastava, Not getting the above error, when I move .check(regex)  function under launch tag, rite after get request.
But need help in capturing the value in jessionid between = and .tomcat >>>'jsessionid=an121kj533n232j53531314353.tomcat_17221212_1101'

Comment: Any response please?